# Would we able to meet the Non Muslim person whom you love in jannah?

Tags: quran, non-muslim, love

Asslamalikum
Alhamdulillah i am a Muslim and I live in India. all Of a sudden I fall in love with my girl best friend who is a non Muslim (Hindu) and because of differeces of cast we cant unite.
I love her so much but since Muslims can't marry a women until she believes so I can't have her as my wife. So my question is WOULD WE ABLE TO MEET THE NON MUSLIM ONES IN PARADISE AS I LOVE HER VERY MUCH BUT I CANT BE WITH HER IN THIS WORLDY LIFE.
I am very depressed these days and I have turned my self to Allah the creator and but I can't find the solution to it.
SINCE ALLAH SAID I WILL GRANT EVERYTHING TO MY SERVANTS IN PARADISE SO WILL HE GRANT ME THE PERSON WHOM I LOVE IN PARADISE?

Comment: You can give dawah to her.

Answer (score 1):

Walekum salaam brother.

First of all the relationship that you have/had with her, whether it is that of love that you have for her now, or the friendship that you had with her earlier, is haraam. You should distance yourself from her, cut all contacts, lest it becomes a source of further fitnah for you. And repent to Allaah (ﷻ) sincerely.

Secondly, you should make dua to Allaah (ﷻ) to grant you a righteous Muslimah wife, who will be a coolness for your eyes and your heart and ask Allaah (ﷻ) to put love between you and her. In sha Allaah, this will make you forget the girl in question, leaving not regrets.

Thirdly, Jannah is the ultimate reward that Allaah (ﷻ) has prepared for the believers. What you will get there is far better that anything that you can expect in this life. Be righteous and strive to please Allaah (ﷻ) to get Jannah, and be assured that what you will get there will make you forget anything that you wished for in this dunya.

Lastly, like others have mentioned, giving dawah to her is also an option. But I am afraid that if you contact her even for giving dawah, it will be a source of fitnah for you. If you can find someone else to give dawah to her, that would be great. Otherwise, focus on the above three points and there will be no regrets, in sha Allaah (ﷻ).

And Allaah (ﷻ) knows the best.

Answer (score 0):

See

Allah grant every wish of a person who entered in paradise. I can't say with 100% surety  but **I think if you will ask her Allah might grant your wish**.

You can have her in this life too. Just give her dawah and teach her about Islam and if she asks any questions then explain the answer.

Answer (score 0):

islam is a religion of mercy and justice. you can pray for her and give her dawah and give her advice or give her leaflets. i would advise moving if you are living with her.that leaves us with the queatin:Can a Muslim live with a non Muslim? Consequently, it also means that Muslims are allowed to live in a non-Muslim country or under a non-Muslim government, as long as they have the freedom to worship their religion and can experience basic human rights. There is no reason or compulsion for Muslims who live in such situation to move but it would be reasonable and advisable to move to a muslim country.
allah is the most wisest